# Which techniques is used to reduce the number of page table entries in the memory?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

I was studying OS, Paging to be precise. The above question came up. I am guessing it to be  Lookaside Translation Buffer but confused since it is used to reduce the number of physical memory access while calculating an address from a page table.

Well, am I right? Or there is some other technique?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it.

Its the Two Level Page Table implementation, which reduces the amount of virtual memory allocated to the page table.

Thanks!